# PHP Function using javascript / jquery hiding div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a php function:

```
function myfunc() {

//then I have a div...

echo '<div class="overlay">';
echo "<button onclick=\"$('.overlay').hide();\">Close</button>";
echo '</div>';

}
```

My problem is that when I click on the close button the div is not hiding.

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: Any error message in the JavaScript console?

Comment: No, I can see no errors in the js console

Comment: your code is working correctly no problem in that check one again

Comment: You may need to escape the `$`, since it's inside a double-quoted string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avoid to hardcode javascript handlers and inline events inside the output of php code: do instead

```
echo '<div class="overlay">';
echo "<button>Close</button>";
echo '</div>';
```

and previously insert in your page this code that detects a click on your button using event delegation

```
<script>
  $(document).on('click', '.overlay button', function() {
      $(this).parent().hide()
  });
</script>
```

Comment: `button` is child of `overlay`. Why event delegation?

Comment: Sorry, misread the markup. Updated. I've used event delegation because AFAIK that could be the response of an ajax call (so the code could be injected later on DOM) and, as a general rule, if you have many elements to handle, this approach is better than attaching an handler on each element

Comment: I tried the code above but it's just hiding the iside content of the div and the button but not the actual div

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
<button onclick="this.parentNode.style.display = 'none'; return false;">Close</button>
```

Comment: Tried: echo '<button onclick=\"this.style.display = 'none'; return false;">Close</button>'; but the page goes blank so there's a syntax issues here?

Comment: Since that's a single-quoted string, you need to escape single quotes, not double quotes, inside it.

Comment: Sorry, a bit irresponsible that I just posted without testing x| This one works now. It hides the parentNode which is the div.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
function myfunc() {

//then I have a div...

echo '<div class="overlay"  id="overlay" >';
echo "<button onclick=\"hide()\">Close</button>";
echo '</div>';

}
//using the javascript code:
function hide()
{
    document.getElementById("overlay").style.display="none";

}
```

Comment: Tried it but it didn't hide the div

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$('.overlay button').live('click',function(
    $('.overlay').css({'display': 'none'});
));
```